# how to add google translator for a certain div using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-translate

I want to add the google translate to my web site as like in the following but it doesnt work.although am adding the library it doesnt work.

```
<p id="some">Hello</p>
<input id="trans" value="Translate" type="button">
<script>
 $('#trans').click(function() {
    google.language.translate($('#some').html(), 'en', 'fr',  function(result)         {
       $('#some').html(result.translation);
   });
 });
</script>
 <script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

and i'm getting this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'translate' of undefined at 
HTMLInputElement.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.10.2.js?673:612), 
<anonymous>:4:18) at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-
1.10.2.js?673:612), <anonymous>:5095:9) at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle 
(eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.10.2.js?673:612), <anonymous>:4766:28)
```

Comment: You're adding the library indeed, however you added the library below the script, you can't call a script before adding it's library depending on how sensitive the script is.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the event listener inside [document load](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), so the `google.language.translate` would be initialized after the library load :

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#trans').click(function() {
  google.language.translate($('#some').html(), 'en', 'fr',  function(result)         
  {
     $('#some').html(result.translation);
  });
 });
});
```

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `on` method of jquery. Eg:

```
$( "#trans" ).on( "click", function() {
   //invoke your method here.
});
```